# Multi-process Pandas Groupby Failing to do Anything After Processes Kick Off

Tags: pandas, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I have a fairly large pandas dataframe that is about 600,000 rows by 50 columns. I would like to perform a groupby.agg(custom_function) to get the resulting data. The custom_function is a function that takes the first value of non-null data in the series or returns null if all values in the series are null. (My dataframe is hierarchically sorted by data quality, the first occurrence of a unique key has the most accurate data, but in the event of null data in the first occurrence I want to take values in the second occurence... and so on.)

I have found the basic groupby.agg(custom_function) syntax is slow, so I have implemented multi-processing to speed up the computation. When this code is applied over a dataframe that is ~10,000 rows long the computation takes a few seconds, however, when I try to use the entirety of the data, the process seems to stall out. Multiple processes kick off, but memory and cpu usage stay about the same and nothing gets done.

Here is the trouble portion of the code:

```
# Create list of individual dataframes to feed map/multiprocess function
grouped = combined.groupby(['ID'])
grouped_list = [group for name, group in grouped]
length = len(grouped)

# Multi-process execute single pivot function
print('\nMulti-Process Pivot:')
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    with tqdm.tqdm(total=length) as progress:
        futures = []
        for df in grouped_list:
            future = executor.submit(custom_function, df)
            future.add_done_callback(lambda p: progress.update())
            futures.append(future)
        results = []
        for future in futures:
            result = future.result()
            results.append(result)
```

I think the issue has something to do with the multi-processing (maybe queuing up a job this large is the issue?). I don't understand why a fairly small job creates no issues for this code, but increasing the size of the input data seems to hang it up rather than just execute more slowly. If there is a more efficient way to take the first value in each column per unique ID, I'd be interested to hear it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know why it isn't working, but I think you could use [pd.DataFrame.query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) to pre-select the rows you want to work with, and then process them.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to insert this code before calling future.result():

if future.exception() is not None:
raise future.exception()

In my case there was a pickling problem, so the multiprocessing calls never finished. Unfortunately future.result() doesn't raise any exception so you have to check it yourself, like in the above code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be sure to either convert this post into a comment when you get commenting privilege, or to turn it into a qualified answer (see [answer] for guidance)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).